# Textfield return (null) no matter what

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, null, uitextfield

I have searched stackoverflow for similar problems and have found some, but they did not resolve my problem. I have 3 textfields (name,address,phone) from which I want to get the text. I have declared them in the (.h) file, also the @property, and then @synthesized them in the (.m) file. I have a IBAction for a button declared in the (.h) file and linked up correctly. Now when I push this button I want to get the values from the textfields but NSLog shows they are all (null) even before I do anything with the textfields. Its very simple code, i can't understand why it returns null.

```
//CoreDataViewController.h
@interface coreDataViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *name;
    UITextField *address;
    UITextField *phone;
    UILabel *status;
}

@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *status;

- (IBAction) saveData;
@end
```

---

```
//CoreDataViewController.m
#import "coreDataViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation coreDataViewController
@synthesize name=_name;
@synthesize phone=_phone;
@synthesize address=_address;
@synthesize status=_status;

- (void) saveData
{
    NSLog(@"Name %@ Address %@ Phone %@",self.name.text,self.address.text,self.phone.text);

...some more code (commented out)....
}
```

Comment: Could you check 'name', 'phone', 'address' has any object or is it nil ?

Comment: could you show how you instantiate the view controller.

Comment: First of all if You use cocoa You should use NSTextField but not UITextField. Cocoa is for OSX not iOS. And if You use NStextField You can get value by calling NSString *myString = [theTextField stringValue];

Comment: @GirishKolari how do I check?

Comment: And You do not need self.name You can call name, because You synthesize with _name, so Your NSLog should be like this: NSLog(@"Name %@ Address %@ Phone %@",name.text,address.text,phone.text);

Comment: @JustinBoo yes, I know, those are one of MANY attempts at retrieving the text from the field. I created a simple "HalloWorld" app which retrieves text from a field (the user's name) and that worked fine.

Comment: @JustinBoo: Well, it won't compile if he's using the wrong one, so I think we can infer from the uses of UITextField, UIViewController, and UILabel that he meant Cocoa Touch. As for `self.name` vs. `name`, the latter won't compile, because `name` would refer to a variable, not a property, and no such variable has been declared. `self.name` is a message; `[self name]` is equivalent and either one will work.

Comment: @SimonBarkhuizen have you linked these `UITextField` outlets?

Comment: @SimonBarkhuizen: You can check the values of your properties the same way you're checking the values of their values' properties. You would simply say `self.name` instead of `self.name.text` (and the same for all the other controls).

Comment: @MichałZygar Yes, I have doublechecked, tripplecheck and re-linked them
@ PeterHosey THanks!

Comment: So, what do you get when you log `self.name`, `self.address`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you have incorrectly synthesized iVars.
You use syntax:

```
synthesize name=_name;
```

but in the .h file you have:

```
@interface coreDataViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *name;
    UITextField *address;
    UITextField *phone;
    UILabel *status;
}
```

Change this part to:

```
@interface coreDataViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *_name;
    UITextField *_address;
    UITextField *_phone;
    UILabel *_status;
}
```

Comment: Will fix and report back. thnx

Comment: If I only change the (.h) file like you said, it breaks everything else.

Comment: What do you mean, saying: "breaks everything else"?

Comment: I have to rename all "name"s to "_names" in my (.m) class aswell.

Comment: Of course, you have to change it in all places where you use `name` instead `self.name`. You can also change @synthesize statement, like in post above. Using leading underscores is the most popular coding style in objective-c. But, does your code work?

Comment: @TomWojtkowiak Yes, the code compiles fine and I put in the necessary NSLogs in alot of places and everything seems to work except the textfield return null when i call them NSString *username = self.name.text //(name is the textfield)

Answer (score 0):

Just change below code

write synthesize like this

```
@synthesize name;
@synthesize phone;
@synthesize address;
@synthesize status;
```

ratherthen

```
    @synthesize name=_name;
@synthesize phone=_phone;
@synthesize address=_address;
@synthesize status=_status;
```

Comment: It was like that be4, when it also did not work. Will try again tho.

Comment: Both sets of synthesize directives are valid and the latter set has the advantage of preventing you from accidentally referring to the instance variable when you mean the property.